# How can I make mousewheel work in VB6 IDE?

Tags: ide, vb6, mousewheel

One annoying behavior of the VB6 IDE editor, especially when switching back to it from more recent tools like VS.NET, is that it doesn't recognize the mousewheel!  Maybe VB6 was brought out when most mice didn't have one, but is there a way to fix it so it does recognize the mousewheel?

Comment: This question is a good example to remember: when you think you have a weird question on internet you're never the first one :D

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Microsoft has an extension that can provide the behavior requested. You have to download it from the link below and register it with the steps provided, such as using `regsvr32`

http://download.microsoft.com/download/e/f/b/efb39198-7c59-4ace-a5c4-8f0f88e00d34/vb6mousewheel.exe

Update: Here are the steps

- Download the VB6 Mouse Wheel.exe file that includes the add-in DLL
  and the code that is used to create the add-in DLL.
- Extract the files to a location you have access to.
- Open a command prompt, **run as administrator.**
- Go to the folder you
  extracted the files to.
- type `regsvr32 VB6IDEMouseWheelAddin.dll`, and then click OK
- Start Visual Basic 6.0. Click Add-Ins, and then click Add-in Manager.
- In the Add-in Manager list, click MouseWheel Fix.
- Click to select the Loaded/Unloaded check box, and then click to select the Load on Startup check box.
- Click OK.

Comment: At my company we use a free tool Gazanov VBScroll, which works with VBA and also works in the SDI mode of the VB6 IDE (unlike the MS add-in). http://www.gasanov.net/VBScroll.asp

Comment: thanks for the gasanov solution, apparently the fix posted by microsoft itself doesnt work on my vb installation. but gasanov's works like a charm

Comment: +1 for the gasanov tool : it does actually work, unlike the solution from microsoft itself :)

Comment: MS solution doesn't work. I'm using Excel 2016. First solution does not add anything to the Add-Ins menu in VBA. Second solution complains about compatibility issues with Windows 8.1

Comment: Maybe this is obvious for others, but in order to make this work, I had to run cmd as administrator and run the command there instead of in "Run". Then the rest of it worked just fine.

Comment: Yeah, I got an 0x80004005 error unless I ran regsvr as admin.

Comment: I've not been able to get this extension to work in my case. Sounds like other people also have trouble with it now, but I'm not sure my particular problems are the same as theirs.

Comment: Note: instead of using admin command prompt, you can run VBScroll.exe from Explorer using Shift+RIghtClick -> Run as administrator

Comment: The link for the Microsoft fix is dead.

Comment: Here is a link on sourceforge [https://sourceforge.net/projects/vb6mousewheelfix/](https://sourceforge.net/projects/vb6mousewheelfix/), or direct link to exe from Microsoft [http://download.microsoft.com/download/e/f/b/efb39198-7c59-4ace-a5c4-8f0f88e00d34/vb6mousewheel.exe](http://download.microsoft.com/download/e/f/b/efb39198-7c59-4ace-a5c4-8f0f88e00d34/vb6mousewheel.exe)

Comment: +1 Haven't had to do this for so long that I'd forgotten how to do it! I've updated the answer body with a working download link, pending approval.

Comment: @Andy-Hames (and others):  Is this "just" for enabling the scrollwheel while working within the IDE, or for users of the executable that code compiles?  Because I'm looking for a solution for the latter.

Answer (score 18):

The easiest method that worked for me was just downloading and running the binary from http://www.joebott.com/vb6scrollwheel.htm

**Usage:**

Just run the exe and your VB editors have the scroll.

**Info from the Author:**

> This is a small program that will make your mouse's scroll wheel work
>   in various older programs - mainly Visual Basic 6's code window. I
>   noticed a lot of people coming to this site from Google looking for
>   help with their mouse wheel. So, I decided to fix it.
>
> It is possible to support many programs by adjusting its INI file. The
>   included INI file includes support for:
>
> - VB6 Code Window
> - VB6 Resource Design Window
> - SourceSafe 6 Diff Viewer
> - Windiff VBA Editor

Comment: Ohmigosh this was a life saver. The Microsoft solutions sucks and doesn't work.

Comment: on my machine (Win7x64, last update on 13. Oct. '17) only this solution works.

Comment: Only solution (including MS own addin) still working on Win 10 x64, v1709 build 16299.309. Also, if you're on Win7 or 10, you're likely running VB6.exe as admin, so **remember to run this program as admin too**, as it hooks to the process.

Comment: Download --> Launch exe (nothing shows) --> Launch VB --> Scroll like mouse wheel has just been invented. Jokes appart, only solution working on Win 10 x64 for me too.

Comment: @SebastienServouze it shows a tray icon :)

Answer (score 10):

****Easy way for beginer:****

1. Download Download the VB6 Mouse Wheel.exe file as link: http://download.microsoft.com/download/e/f/b/efb39198-7c59-4ace-a5c4-8f0f88e00d34/vb6mousewheel.exe
2. Run .exe, click unzip (we have VB6IDEMouseWheelAddin.dll)
3. Coppy VB6IDEMouseWheelAddin.dll to System32 (x32bit) or SysWOW64 (x64bit)
4. Run Cmd as Administrator
   5.1 With x32bit:

   C:\WINDOWS\system32>regsvr32 VB6IDEMouseWheelAddin.dll  (in Cdm )

5.2 With x64bit:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>cd C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64

C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64>regsvr32 VB6IDEMouseWheelAddin.dll (IN cmd)
```

6. Open the VB IDE.
7. Go to the 'Add-Ins Manager'.
8. Select 'MouseWheel Fix' in the Available Add-Ins.
9. Check 'Loaded/Unloaded' and 'Load on Startup'.
10. Click 'OK' button.

Comment: Microsoft link not working anymore

Comment: Link is stale (been removed from Microsoft site)... Best bet is to use Wheeler solution above from StayOnTarget

Answer (score 4):

Steps from https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/837910

To install the VB6 IDE Mousewheel Addin:

1. Copy VB6IDEMouseWheelAddin.dll to your local System32 directory and register.
2. Open the VB IDE.
3. Go to the 'Add-Ins Manager'.
4. Select 'MouseWheel Fix' in the Available Add-Ins.
5. Check 'Loaded/Unloaded' and 'Load on Startup'.
6. Click 'OK' button.

You should now be able to use the mousewheel in the code window.

Answer (score 1):

I came across another method ([which was discussed on VBForums](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?858705-RESOLVED-What-happened-to-add-in-names-in-VB6-Add-In-Manager-in-Windows-10-build-1709&p=5260435&viewfull=1#post5260435), advocated by Dilletante and Elroy).

> ...use the **X-Mouse utility** to fix the scroll-wheel. ... it's the only
>   one I've ever found that correctly scrolls when you have your code
>   displayed as a split-window.

[Download website.](http://www.highrez.co.uk/downloads/XMouseButtonControl.htm)

[image]

Since I was [having trouble with the Microsoft add-in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52312909/why-does-the-vb6-ide-refuses-to-load-valid-add-ins) noted in some other answers I tried this and it does work well. Conveniently it also lets you set some options to tune the scrolling behavior and speed.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another external program, [as mentioned in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6380175/3195477).

Download link: [Wheeler](http://vb.mvps.org/tools/Wheeler/)

> Wheeler is a free program that enhances the behavior of your mouse
>   wheel...
>
> Wheeler is a highly configurable program. Here are some highlights:
>
> In addition to scrolling the window under the cursor when you roll the
>   mouse wheel, it's possible to move the keyboard focus to that window...
>   Through the concept of wheelability, you
>   can control how wheel messages are processed on a per window class
>   basis. Scoped window classes allow you to associate window class names
>   with the specific programs that define them, so you don't have to
>   worry about affecting other programs that may unwittingly use the same
>   window class names. ... You can exclude entire programs
>   from the Wheeler treatment.