# Features in VB6 stop working on one of my multiple monitors

Tags: vb6, mousewheel, multiple-monitors

I have 3 monitors with the center monitor being the primary one. When I start VB6 everything works fine on the center and right monitor, but if I maximize the window on the left monitor my scroll wheel (which uses the [VB6 mouse wheel fix](http://support.microsoft.com/?id=837910)) and Ctrl+F for the Find window stop working and continue to not work until I drag the window so most of it is on the center monitor. I have not had any issues with any other programs. Any fix for this?

Comment: This sounds like an issue specific to your program.  Remember that coordinates on that monitor to your left will be negative.  If you can post some code, making a simple test case, we can be of better help.

Comment: It's not my program, it's the actual VB6 designer program. I don't have the source code for that :)

Comment: I have the exact same configuration as you (3 monitors, center primary, using mouse wheel fix) and I don't have any problems like you describe.  Do you have VB6 Service Pack 6 installed?

I should also mention I am using Vista Professional 64 bit.

Comment: Yes, I have SP6 and I'm on Windows 7 32 bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't personally seen the issues you have with a specific monitor not working, but for me (and my Logitech mouse), I have tried the VB6 mouse wheel fix you mentioned and it didn't work.

Instead, I had to use [Wheeler](http://vb.mvps.org/tools/Wheeler/).  Check out the link for the full description, but the bottom line is it's the only thing that helps me use the mousewheel in the VB6 IDE on *any* monitor.