# I want to install VB6 on windows 10 OS. I need to work on VBP project so I have to install VB6 seamlessly

Tags: visual-studio, vb6, windows-10

I have VB6 enterprise version set up but it is not able to complete its installation.(Hang)

I have tried installer from following link: http://nuke.vbcorner.net/Tools/VisualStudio6Installer/tabid/93/language/it-IT/Default.aspx

The condition for above installation you need to have msdn image files ready which I don't have. How can I get VB6 installed on Windows 10?

Comment: So you want to know how to pirate VB6?

Comment: No i have VB6 installation files but some how it is not getting installed? Folders and all gets created but installer hangs at very last moment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does the VB6 IDE run on Windows 7 / 8 / 10 64-bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2501061/does-the-vb6-ide-run-on-windows-7-8-10-64-bit)

Comment: If the installer hangs, it may be that you have the data components option checked. Be sure that is unchecked.

Answer (score 10):

I followed the instructions [here](http://www.planetsourcecode.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=74428&lngWId=1) to create VB 6 and VB6 SP6 installers for Windows 10.

Simple and fast to create, and worked without issue.

Comment: You should probably add the general steps in the process, or at least a line about the trick being to recreate the installer.

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://www.fortypoundhead.com/showcontent.asp?artid=23993) should work for you, but make sure you read through all the comments as the zero-byte file seems to have stopped working on later builds so there are some workarounds others shared. Though honestly, if all it is doing is stopping a reboot, I don't see why that matters. Copied main text here in case link dies some day.

> **Stop the Reboot**
>
> As in my previous tutorials for installing VB6 on Windows 7 and Windows 8, you'll want to create a zero byte file called MSJAVA.DLL. Creating this file in C:\Windows will prevent the need for a reboot at the end of the installation. If you're not familiar with how to create a zero-byte file, just click that link back there.
>
> **Let's Get Started**
>
> The first thing that you'll notice after inserting your installation media is the Program Compatibility Assistant popping up with a warning of known compatibility issues. Close it - we need to run setup manually. If you have autorun turned off, you'll get this pop up when you run setup.
>
> Navigate to the installation media, and find the setup program. Right click setup.exe, and select Run As Administrator. Very important! Setup needs to do some registry twiddling and register some items with Windows, and won't be able to do it without the necessary permissions.
>
> Simply click the option that reads Run the program without getting help, and the main setup wizard will start.
>
> The first few screens are the usual stuff, things you've seen before:
>
> - Welcome Screen - Gives you the opportunity to vew the readme. Just
>     click Next unless your really want to read it!
> - EULA - Yep, it's the End User License Agreement. Scroll it, then
>     signal your acceptance in the appropriate radio button, then click
>     Next.
> - Product Number and USer ID - This is where you put in your user name,
>     company name and product ID. Fill in the fields as you see fit, and
>     click Next to continue with the wizard.
> - What to install - Two options here; VB6 Enterprise Edition, or Server
>     Applications. I am going with the first option
> - Common Installation folder - I accepted the default for this:
>     C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Common
> - Welcome and Warning - Copyright protection, inability to update files
>     in use, etc. Click Continue to move on
> - Visual Basic 6.0 Enterprise Setup - This is where the actual
>     installation of VB6 begins. Your PID is shown on the screen, and you
>     are invited to write it down if you have not already. Click Ok to
>     continue
>
> **Main Installation**
>
> On the first screen of the ACM Setup, leave the installation folder at the default, and click the Custom option for setup. The next screen will be the options list.
>
> I don't use SourceSafe, so I cleared the checkbox. If you use SourceSafe, then by all means leave it checked for installation.
>
> **Very important <sup>(editor's note: see comment at the end)</sup>** - Clear the checkbox for Data Access. If you don't, set up will hang at the end of the installation. Not sure for the real reason, but the theory is that setup is trying to register with Windows on a non-existent service. Clearing the Data Access checkbox stops this registration attempt.
>
> Click Continue to carry on with the installation process. At this point, if you didn't create the empty MSJAVA.DLL file in C:\Windows, you'll get a restart Windows prompt. Go ahead and restart if you need to, I'll wait.
>
> In any event, you'll get an MSDN installation wizard. I decline this, since much more information is available online anyway.
>
> Now you'll get an option Server Setups dialog. If you want to install BackOffice, Visual SourceSafe Server, or SNA server, you have the opportunity at this point. I don't use these items, so I just click Next to blow by it.
>
> Finally, we get to the last screen of the wizard. Un-check the Register Now checkbox, and click Finish.
>
> **Getting VB6 Running for the First Time**
>
> You can find the new shortcuts in your start menu, under the usual Microsoft Visual Basic 6.0 program group. You might be tempted to just fire it up straight away, and you can. But, you'll receive a nasty error about Automation, Error accessing the registry. You can blow by the error, but you'll just keep getting it every time you fire up VB6, and some data-access related items won't work correctly.
>
> So, to get past this behavior, right-click the Microsoft Visual Basic 6.0 program icon in the start menu group, and select Run As Administrator. Click Yes in the resulting UAC dialog, and VB6 will start normally, presenting the new project wizard.
>
> Ok, the first post-setup task is complete. Now on to the final piece.
>
> **Fixing the IDE Chug**
>
> Now before you start building a new project or editing an existing one, there is one more bit of configuration you might need to do. In running the IDE in a Windows 10 virtual machine, I've found that the IDE is somewhat sluggish when sizing and/or placing controls on a form, as well as sizing the form itself. This problem also presented itself in Windows 7 and Windows 8. We need to configure a couple things about the run properties of the IDE to fix this.
>
> Be sure the IDE is closed, then right-click the start menu icon again. This time select Open file location.
>
> In the explorer window that appears, right click the Microsoft Visual Basic 6.0 icon, and select properties. In the Properties window, select the Compatibility tab. On the Compatibility tab, click the Change settings for all users button.
>
> In the new VB6 Properties window, place a tick mark in the Run this program in compatibility mode for: checkbox, and select Windows XP (Service Pack 3) from the drop down.
>
> Under Settings, check the Reduced color mode checkbox, and change the dropdown to 16-bit (65536) color.
>
> Put a check mark in the Disable display scaling on high DPI settings.
>
> Click Ok, then Ok again.

*Install with Data Access (from last comment as of 7/3/16)*

> I was succesfully able to install Visual Studio 6 Professional on
>   windows 10 Pro 64bit WITH Data Access.  It is very simple, just
>   install VS6 as you normally would with Data Access enabled, it will
>   freeze when you try to finalize the install.  Allow it to freeze, then
>   end the installation task.  You will still have all the install files
>   and will be able to run the program.  Now, you will need to install
>   the VB6 service pack 6, but it won't allow you to since visual studio
>   did not install correctly.  To fix this, install VS6 over again, this
>   time uncheck data access components, install as normal.  Afterward,
>   run the service pack and you should be good to go.

Comment: What error is it giving you when you try to run it?

Comment: it is showing another version of visual studio is already install Do you want to set up program? Click : Yes, It completes the set and last message window comes mentioning 'Set up is updating the files' and this dialog box never closes until i kill the process through task manager. Hush!!!!

Comment: I recall when I set this up on Win 7 that I read VB6 had to be installed before any other VS version so that is what I did. His instructions are on a clean machine so maybe there really are issues if newer versions are installed. However, I recall seeing that error or one very close to it whenever I would open VB6 to work on a project except I'd just cancel out of it and everything would work fine. I'm not sure what caused it but months later it stopped doing that but I don't know what changed.

Comment: finally i created VM of XP and installed VB in VM !!! WorkAround !!! . Thanks for the reply BTW

Comment: These (from forty pound head) are the instructions our shop uses to install the VB6 IDE on Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

Update to my above post about the Help facility.  Even though I installed the MSDN Library using the CDs and copied an old winhlp32.exe from an XP machine, that allowed me to view ".HLP" files from Win10, but from within VB6 no help worked.  Finally, I was able to go to this website and download vshelp.exe.

http://download.cnet.com/Visual-Studio-Help-Engine-for-MSDN-Enables-MSDN-menu-functionality-in-Visual-FoxPro/3000-2213_4-10727794.html

It ran in a flash and made all the Visual Studio / Visual Basic 6.0 Help work including context sensitive help.

Answer (score 1):

The VB6 installer wizard [Visual Studio 6.0 Installer wizard](http://nuke.vbcorner.net/) to install the VB6 programming IDE and the MSDN library has been downloaded over 175,000 times.

You need to have your VB6 or VS6 CD and your VB6 serial number.

It works on Windows 7, 8.x, or 10 32bit or 64bit.

Answer (score 0):

I got VS6/VB6 Running under Windows 10 by following the many posts on the Internet involving 1) lowering UAC + REGEDIT check, 2) copy a real MSJAVA.DLL from the VS Install Disk 1 IE4 Folder (un-7-Zip MSJAVX86.EXE) dragging MSJAVA.DLL to all the Windows SYSTEM32/SYSWOW64 folders (a zero byte MSJAVA.DLL no longer works), 3) placing and REGSVR32'ing dx7vb.dll (in the same folders as prior step), then using MSCONFIG to boot Win10 in Safe mode, and running the install from the original MSDN CDs. [No CDs?  Read on]

For VB6 you only need DISC 1, both MSDN CDs, and the Service Pack 6 (get it on the Internet).  WARNING: The install for DISC 1 will become "Not Responding".  In my case, after an hour, I figured it must be done, so let Win10 close it as a "not responding window", and it went on with the MSDN and it worked.  (you can also install MSDN standalone from the CDs later)  If you can't get the SP6 update to work try by putting it on a Thumbdrive in the root and call the Volume name VS6SP6.  In fact, for VB6 if you don't have the CDs anymore, you can create CDs with the contents of each install folder provided you give the CD Volume Label names as follows:

VB6 Disc 1 Volume Label: VSP600ENU1

VB6 Disc 3 Volume Label: DN600ENU1

VB6 Disc 4 Volume Label: DN600ENU2

When done, restore MSCONFIG to normal boot then raise your UAC back up.

One Glitch, I've not yet fixed. ".HLP" files are not supported under Windows 10, so no VB6 Help will be available (that's MSDN).  However, I've read (but not tried) that I can copy WINHLP32.EXE from an XP machine to Win10 Windows dir.  But first I've gotta get my old XP machine running.

For now, I'm re-developing all my VB programs (without the HELP facility) under Windows 10 Home Edition just fine and merrily doing my compiles again!

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I made this script a while ago because I was having trouble with the installers and fixes I found around the internet. It incorporates all the tricks and tips that I found around the internet into one powershell script.

To run the script you will need to following:

- VB6 Installer
- [Service Pack 6](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5721)
- [Mouse Wheel Fix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1039685/4533115) (Optional, set `-SkipMouseWheel` switch to skip.)

Each of the above should be placed in its own folder. If you save (and then dot-source) the script in a folder that contains these three folders it'll auto-detect everything for you. You can also set your current location in powershell to this folder and copy the script directly to you session and it'll detect everything as well.

Once the script is dot-sourced or pasted in an elevated powershell instance you can run it by calling `Install-VB6`.

It also has the following parameters if you want to override any default behaviour:

| Parameter | Type | Usage |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `Vb6InstallerPath` | String | Path of main VB6 Installer folder |
| `SP6InstallerPath` | String | Path of Service Pack 6 Installer folder |
| `SkipMouseWheel` | Switch | Skip installing the Mouse Wheel Fixer folder |
| `MouseWheelPath` | String | Path of Mouse Wheel fixer. Ignored if `-SkipMouseWheel` is specified |
| `Regsvr32Path` | String | Path to regsvr32.exe. Uses '%SYSTEMROOT%\SysWoW64\regsvr32.exe' if not specified |
| `RegEditPath` | String | Path to regedit.exe. '%SYSTEMROOT%\regedit.exe' if not specified |
| `OrganizationName` | String | Sets the organization name in the VB6 installer |

**Notes:**

1. The VB6 and SP6 installer don't like being run from a network drive, so the script will stop if it detects one of the install folders is not on a local drive.
2. I've only tested this with VB6 Pro, not VB6 Enterprise.
3. It doesn't install MSDN.

### Install-VB6.ps1

```
#Requires -RunAsAdministrator
#Requires -Version 3

<#
.SYNOPSIS
Installs VB6 to the computer.

.DESCRIPTION
Installs VB6 ide with Service Pack 6 and (optional) Mouse Wheel Fix to the local computer.

.PARAMETER Vb6InstallerPath
The path to the VB6 installer folder.

.PARAMETER SP6InstallerPath
The path the the Service Pack 6 installer folder.

.PARAMETER SkipMouseWheel
Skip installing the Mouse Wheel fix.

.PARAMETER MouseWheelPath
The path the Mouse wheel fix folder.

.PARAMETER Regsvr32Path
The path to RegSvr32.exe

.PARAMETER OrganizationName
The organization name

.PARAMETER RegEditPath
The path to regedit.exe
#>
Function Install-VB6{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [string]$Vb6InstallerPath,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [string]$SP6InstallerPath,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [switch]$SkipMouseWheel,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [string]$MouseWheelPath,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [string]$Regsvr32Path,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [string]$OrganizationName,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [string]$RegEditPath
    )


    # Tests if the path is a local path. The installer doesn't like network paths.
    function Test-LocalDrive{
        [CmdletBinding()]
        [OutputType([bool])]
        param(
            [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
                        Position=0)]
            [string]$Path
        )
        begin{
            $localDrives = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_logicaldisk -Filter "DriveType<>4" -Property "DeviceID" | Foreach-Object {$_.DeviceID.Replace(":", "")}
        }
        process{
            if(!([bool](Test-Path -Path $Path))){
                return $false
            }

            $item = Get-Item -Path $Path
            $drive = $item.PSDrive

            if($null -eq $drive){
                return $false
            }

            return ($localDrives -contains $drive.Name)
        }
    }

    function Search-ForFile{
        [CmdletBinding()]
        [OutputType([System.IO.FileInfo])]
        param(
            [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
                        Position=0)]
            [string]$File,
            [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
                        Position=1)]
            [string]$CurrentLocation,
            [switch]$IncludeSubDirectory
        )
        process{
            $newPath = $currentLocation
            if($IncludeSubDirectory.IsPresent){
                $newPath = Join-Path -Path $newPath -ChildPath "*"
            }
            $newPath = Join-Path -Path $newPath -ChildPath $file

            $item = @(Get-Item -Path $newPath)

            if($null -eq $item -or $item.Count -eq 0 -or $null -eq $item[0]){
                throw ("Could Not find the {0} file." -f $file)
            }

            return $item[0]
        }
    }

    

#region Setting Up File Paths
    $currentLocation = $PSScriptRoot
    if([System.String]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($currentLocation)){
        $currentLocation = (Get-Location)
    }
    if([System.String]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($currentLocation)){
        throw "Unable to determine current location"
    }

    if(!$PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey("Vb6InstallerPath") -or [System.String]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($Vb6InstallerPath)){
        if(!(Test-LocalDrive -Path ($currentLocation))){
            Write-Error "The script cannot be ran from a network share."
            Write-Host -NoNewLine 'Press any key to continue...';
            $null = $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey('NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown');
            return
        }
        $installerInfo = Search-ForFile -File "SETUP.EXE" -CurrentLocation $currentLocation -IncludeSubDirectory
        $installFolder = $installerInfo.DirectoryName
    }
    else {
        if(!(Test-LocalDrive -Path ($Vb6InstallerPath))){
            Write-Error "The VB6 Installer Path cannot be a share."
            Write-Host -NoNewLine 'Press any key to continue...';
            $null = $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey('NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown');
            return
        }
        $installFolder = $Vb6InstallerPath
        $installerInfo = Search-ForFile -File "SETUP.EXE" -CurrentLocation $installFolder
    }

    $installer2Info = Search-ForFile -File "ACMSETUP.EXE" -CurrentLocation $installFolder -IncludeSubDirectory

    $installLocation = $installerInfo.FullName
    $install2Location = $installer2Info.FullName

    if(!$PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey("SP6InstallerPath") -or [System.String]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($SP6InstallerPath)){
        if(!(Test-LocalDrive -Path ($currentLocation))){
            Write-Error "The script cannot be ran from a network share."
            Write-Host -NoNewLine 'Press any key to continue...';
            $null = $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey('NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown');
            return
        }
        $SP6Info = Search-ForFile -File "setupsp6.exe" -CurrentLocation $currentLocation -IncludeSubDirectory
        $SP6Folder = $SP6Info.DirectoryName
    }
    else {
        if(!(Test-LocalDrive -Path ($SP6InstallerPath))){
            Write-Error "The SP6 Installer Path cannot be a network share."
            Write-Host -NoNewLine 'Press any key to continue...';
            $null = $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey('NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown');
            return
        }
        $SP6Folder = $SP6InstallerPath
        $SP6Info = Search-ForFile -File "setupsp6.exe" -CurrentLocation $SP6Folder
    }

    $SP6Location = $SP6Info.FullName

    if(!$SkipMouseWheel.IsPresent){
        if(!$PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey("MouseWheelPath") -or [System.String]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($MouseWheelPath)){
            if(!(Test-LocalDrive -Path ($currentLocation))){
                Write-Error "The script cannot be ran from a network share."
                Write-Host -NoNewLine 'Press any key to continue...';
                $null = $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey('NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown');
                return
            }
            $MouseWheelDllInfo           = Search-ForFile -File "VB6IDEMouseWheelAddin.dll" -CurrentLocation $currentLocation -IncludeSubDirectory
            $MouseWheelRegistryInfo      = Search-ForFile -File "VBA Mouse Wheel Fix.reg" -CurrentLocation $currentLocation -IncludeSubDirectory
        }
        else {
            if(!(Test-LocalDrive -Path ($SP6InstallerPath))){
                Write-Error "The Mouse Wheel Path cannot be a network share."
                Write-Host -NoNewLine 'Press any key to continue...';
                $null = $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey('NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown');
                return
            }
            $MouseWheelDllInfo           = Search-ForFile -File "VB6IDEMouseWheelAddin.dll" -CurrentLocation $MouseWheelPath
            $MouseWheelRegistryInfo      = Search-ForFile -File "VBA Mouse Wheel Fix.reg" -CurrentLocation $MouseWheelPath
        }

        $MouseWheelDll           = $MouseWheelDllInfo.FullName
        $MouseWheelRegistry      = $MouseWheelRegistryInfo.FullName
    }

    if(!$PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey("Regsvr32Path") -or [System.String]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($Regsvr32Path)){
        $regSvrPath = "$($env:systemroot)\SysWoW64\regsvr32.exe"
    }
    else{
        $regSvrPath = $Regsvr32Path
    }

    if(!$PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey("RegEditPath") -or [System.String]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($RegEditPath)){
        $RegEditPath = "$($env:systemroot)\regedit.exe"
    }
#endregion Setting Up File Paths

#region Test Required Installer Paths Exist

    if(!([bool](Test-Path -Path $regSvrPath))){
        Write-Error ("Unable to find '{0}'.`r`nThe exe must exist." -f $regSvrPath)
        Write-Host -NoNewLine 'Press any key to continue...';
        $null = $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey('NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown');
        return
    }

    if(!([bool](Test-Path -Path $RegEditPath))){
        Write-Error ("Unable to find '{0}'.`r`nThe exe must exist." -f $RegEditPath)
        Write-Host -NoNewLine 'Press any key to continue...';
        $null = $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey('NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown');
        return
    }

    if(!$SkipMouseWheel.IsPresent){
        if(!([bool](Test-Path -Path $MouseWheelDll))){
            Write-Error ("Unable to find '{0}'.`r`nThe 'MouseWheel' Folder must be in the same directory as the install script and the file must exist." -f $MouseWheelDll)
            Write-Host -NoNewLine 'Press any key to continue...';
            $null = $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey('NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown');
            return
        }

        if(!([bool](Test-Path -Path $MouseWheelRegistry))){
            Write-Error ("Unable to find '{0}'.`r`nThe 'MouseWheel' Folder must be in the same directory as the install script and the file must exist." -f $MouseWheelRegistry)
            Write-Host -NoNewLine 'Press any key to continue...';
            $null = $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey('NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown');
            return
        }
    }

    if(!([bool](Test-Path -Path $installFolder))){
        Write-Error ("Unable to find '{0}'.`r`nThe 'Installer' Folder must be in the same directory as the install script." -f $installFolder)
        Write-Host -NoNewLine 'Press any key to continue...';
        $null = $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey('NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown');
        return
    }

    if(!([bool](Test-Path -Path $installLocation))){
        Write-Error ("Unable to find '{0}'.`r`nThe 'Installer' Folder must be in the same directory as the install script and the file must exist." -f $installLocation)
        Write-Host -NoNewLine 'Press any key to continue...';
        $null = $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey('NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown');
        return
    }

    if(!([bool](Test-Path -Path $install2Location))){
        Write-Error ("Unable to find '{0}'.`r`nThe 'Installer' Folder must be in the same directory as the install script and the file must exist." -f $install2Location)
        Write-Host -NoNewLine 'Press any key to continue...';
        $null = $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey('NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown');
        return
    }

    if(!([bool](Test-Path -Path $SP6Location))){
        Write-Error ("Unable to find '{0}'.`r`nThe 'SP6' Folder must be in the same directory as the install script and the file must exist." -f $SP6Location)
        Write-Host -NoNewLine 'Press any key to continue...';
        $null = $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey('NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown');
        return
    }

#endregion Test Required Installer Paths Exist

#region Installer Compatibility
    # The installer doesn't auto-elevate to run as an administrator.
    # We are setting the required keys in the registry to force the installers to run as administrator
    # Same as running the 'troubleshoot compatibilty' wizard and selecting the exe's to run as admins.
    Write-Host "Setting compatibility mode on setup files."
    $layersPath = "REGISTRY::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers"
    if(![bool](Test-Path -Path $layersPath)){
        New-Item -Path $layersPath -Force | Out-Null
    }

    $registryPath = Get-Item -LiteralPath $layersPath
    if($null -eq $registryPath.GetValue($installLocation, $null)){
        New-ItemProperty -Path $layersPath -Name $installLocation -Value "^ WINXPSP3" -PropertyType "String" -Force | Out-Null
    }

    if($null -eq $registryPath.GetValue($SP6Location, $null)){
        New-ItemProperty -Path $layersPath -Name $SP6Location -Value "^ WINXPSP3" -PropertyType "String" -Force | Out-Null
    }
#endregion Installer Compatibility

#region Previous Install Cleanup
    # Locations and keys where old vb6 installs can live.
    Write-Host "Cleaning up previous install."

    $itemsToDelete = @(
        "C:\Program Files*\Microsoft Visual Studio\Common",
        "C:\Program Files*\Microsoft Visual Studio\MSDN",
        "C:\Program Files*\Microsoft Visual Studio\MSDN98",
        "C:\Program Files*\Microsoft Visual Studio\VB98",
        "C:\Program Files*\Microsoft Visual Studio\VC98",
        "C:\Program Files*\Microsoft Visual Studio\*.HTM",
        "C:\Program Files*\Microsoft Visual Studio\*.TXT",
        "C:\Program Files*\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\MSDesigners98",
        "C:\Program Files*\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\MSDN",
        "C:\Program Files*\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\VS98",
        "C:\Program Files*\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Wizards98",
        "REGISTRY::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\DevStudio",
        "REGISTRY::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\HTML Help Collections",
        "REGISTRY::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\MSVSDG",
        "REGISTRY::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Visual Basic\6.0",
        "REGISTRY::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Visual Component Manager",
        "REGISTRY::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Visual Modeler",
        "REGISTRY::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\6.0",
        "REGISTRY::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\DevStudio",
        "REGISTRY::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\HTML Help Collections",
        "REGISTRY::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\MSVSDG",
        "REGISTRY::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Visual Basic\6.0",
        "REGISTRY::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Visual Component Manager",
        "REGISTRY::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Visual Modeler",
        "REGISTRY::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\6.0",
        "REGISTRY::HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\DevStudio",
        "REGISTRY::HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\MSVSDG",
        "REGISTRY::HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Visual Basic\6.0",
        "REGISTRY::HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Visual Modeler",
        "REGISTRY::HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualFoxPro",
        "REGISTRY::HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\6.0"
    )

    $itemsToDelete | Where-Object { Test-Path -Path $_ } | Remove-Item -Force -Recurse | Out-Null
#endregion Previous Install Cleanup

#region Installer Registry Permissions
    # The installer needs to be able to write to 'HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\RDSServer.DataFactory\Clsid'
    # but since the installer isn't built for windows and we have to force it to run as an administrator
    # we have to give explicit permissions for your computers Administrators group to write to this key (and all its children)
    Write-Host "Setting required permissions for installing user on registry."

    $registryPermissionPath = "REGISTRY::HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\RDSServer.DataFactory\Clsid"
    Write-Host "`tSetting Up required information."
    $acl = Get-ACL -Path $registryPermissionPath
    $oldOwner = [System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]::new($acl.Owner)
    $administratorIdentity = [System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]::new("Administrators")

    Write-Host "`tGiving the script required permissions."
    $import = '[DllImport("ntdll.dll")] public static extern int RtlAdjustPrivilege(ulong a, bool b, bool c, ref bool d);'
    $ntdll = Add-Type -Member $import -Name NtDll -PassThru
    $privileges = @{ SeTakeOwnership = 9; SeBackup =  17; SeRestore = 18 }
    foreach ($i in $privileges.Values) {
        $null = $ntdll::RtlAdjustPrivilege($i, 1, 0, [ref]0)
    }

    Write-Host "`tGettting The registry key."
    $regKey = [Microsoft.Win32.Registry]::ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey("RDSServer.DataFactory\Clsid", 'ReadWriteSubTree', 'TakeOwnership')

    # We force the Administrators group to be the owner on the key so we can then add required the permissions.
    Write-Host "`tSetting Owner."
    $acl.SetOwner($administratorIdentity)
    $regKey.SetAccessControl($acl)

    Write-Host "`tSetting Permission."
    $permission = [System.Security.AccessControl.RegistryAccessRule]::new($administratorIdentity, "FullControl", "ContainerInherit", "InheritOnly", "Allow")
    $acl.AddAccessRule($permission)
    $permission2 = [System.Security.AccessControl.RegistryAccessRule]::new($administratorIdentity, "FullControl", "Allow")
    $acl.AddAccessRule($permission2)
    $regKey.SetAccessControl($acl)

    # Reset the owner to clean-up
    Write-Host "`tResetting Owner."
    $acl.SetOwner($oldOwner)
    $regKey.SetAccessControl($acl)

#endregion Installer Registry Permissions

#region Install
    Write-Host "`tStarting Install."
    $tempPath = [System.IO.Path]::GetTempPath()
    $tempFolder = Join-Path -Path $tempPath -ChildPath ([System.Guid]::NewGuid().ToString("n"))
    New-Item -Path $tempFolder -ItemType Directory -Force | Out-Null
    $KeyFile = Join-Path -Path $tempFolder -ChildPath ("{0}.dat" -f [System.Guid]::NewGuid().ToString("n"))
    $keyFileText = @"
REGEDIT4

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\6.0\Setup\Microsoft Visual Basic\SetupWizard]
"aspo"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\6.0\Setup\Microsoft Visual Basic\SetupWizard]
"aspo"=dword:00000000
"@
    $keyFileText | Set-Content -Path $keyFile -Force

    & $RegEditPath /S $KeyFile
    
    [string[]]$installerArguments = ("/T", "VB98PRO.stf", "/S", $installFolder, "/n", ($env:USERNAME), "/k", "0000000000", "/b", "1", "/qn1")

    if($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey("OrganizationName") -and ![System.String]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($OrganizationName)){
        $installerArguments += "/o"
        $installerArguments += $OrganizationName
    }
    Start-Process -FilePath $install2Location -wait -NoNewWindow -ArgumentList $installerArguments
    Start-Process -FilePath $SP6Location -wait -NoNewWindow -ArgumentList ("/qn1")

    Write-Host "Setting Vb6 Compatibility"
    $vb6ExeLocations = @(Get-Item -Path "C:\Program Files*\Microsoft Visual Studio\VB98\VB6.EXE" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName)
    $registryPath = Get-Item -LiteralPath $layersPath
    foreach($vb6ExeLocation in $vb6ExeLocations){
        if($null -eq $registryPath.GetValue($vb6ExeLocation, $null)){
            New-ItemProperty -Path $layersPath -Name $vb6ExeLocation -Value "^ WINXPSP3" -PropertyType "String" -Force | Out-Null
        }
    }

    if(!$SkipMouseWheel.IsPresent){

        Write-Host "Installing Mouse Wheel"
        & $regSvrPath /s $MouseWheelDll
        & $RegEditPath /S $MouseWheelRegistry

        $registryHeaderText = @"
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00


"@

        $registryItemFormat = @"
        [{0}\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Visual Basic\6.0\Addins\VB6IDEMouseWheelAddin.Connect]
        "FriendlyName"="MouseWheel Fix"
        "LoadBehavior"=dword:00000003
        "CommandLineSafe"=dword:00000000
"@

        $users = Get-ChildItem -Path "REGISTRY::HKEY_USERS" | Where-Object {$_.Name -notlike "*_Classes"} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
        $content = $registryHeaderText

        # Install for every user.
        foreach($user in $users){
            $content += ($registryItemFormat -f $user)
        }

        $MouseWheelApplyRegistry = Join-Path -Path $tempFolder -ChildPath ("{0}.reg" -f [System.Guid]::NewGuid().ToString("n"))

        $content | Set-Content -Path $MouseWheelApplyRegistry -Force
        Start-Process $RegEditPath -wait -NoNewWindow -ArgumentList ("/S", $MouseWheelApplyRegistry)

        Write-Host "You will still need to enable Mouse Wheel fix in the VB6 IDE." -BackgroundColor Black -ForegroundColor Red
        Write-Host "Open a Visual Basic project and go to 'Add-Ins' -> 'Add-In Manager...' " -BackgroundColor Black -ForegroundColor Red
        Write-Host "Select 'MouseWheel Fix' and click 'Loaded/Unloaded' and 'Load on Startup'"  -BackgroundColor Black -ForegroundColor Red
    }

    Remove-Item -Path $tempFolder -Force -Recurse | Out-Null
#endregion Install

    Write-Host "Install Complete"
    Write-Host -NoNewLine 'Press any key to continue...';
    $null = $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey('NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Microsoft's support statement for the VB6 programming environment is here...
[VB6 support statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-basic-6/visual-basic-6-support-policy)

Comment: The VB6 IDE runs fine on Windows 10.