# How to install VB6 on Win 10?

Tags: windows-10, vb6

I'm trying to get VB6 installed on Win10, apparently there's a 'wizard' from Giorgio Brausi, 'Visual Basic/Studio 6 installer' but the web site seems to have gone. How can I do this?

Comment: I also wasn't able to find the wizard.  However, I have done this several times manually and it isn't that hard.  Here is  [a link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38169307/5162073) with a lot of good discussion and instructions.

Comment: VB6 runs fine on Windows 10 (64-bit Pro) here without any special installation wizard. There are one or two 'tricks' to allow it to install and instructions for those are [here](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/install-visual-basic-6-vb6-in-windows-7-without-microsoft-virtual-machine-for-java/). I assume the wizard you are talking about applied those automatically.

Comment: [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52001443/cannot-install-vb6-ide-on-windows-10/52015989#52015989) a post I made a while back that describes the installation method I use on Windows-10-Pro.  It has been completely reliable, on many different machines.  I had tried several other methods, including the wizard, and this is the way that always worked for me.  (I never got the wizard to work...)

Comment: Hi, thanks. I've already tried the 'Raymond' one and that didn't work. I've copied the links and I'll have another go later today.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does the VB6 IDE run on Windows 7 / 8 / 10 64-bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2501061/does-the-vb6-ide-run-on-windows-7-8-10-64-bit)

Comment: Another dupe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52001443/cannot-install-vb6-ide-on-windows-10/52015989#52015989

Answer (score 1):

The simplest end easiest way I found is using a program called [VB6InstallerSetup](http://nuke.vbcorner.net/Articles/VB60/VisualStudio6Installer/tabid/93/language/en-US/Default.aspx).

You just follow the steps in the wizard and it does everything for you.

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/dotnet/visual-basic/mouse-wheel-events-do-not-work) is a fix to get the mouse wheel to work after the install

Answer (score 0):

Sorry not sure exactly which method worked but after another dozen failures today getting combinations of:

'visual studio 6.0 setup was not completed successfully'
or
'install Service pack 6'...which failed as it detected a newer version was loaded
or
'instal MSDN'

it finally worked. To get it loaded took two full days in the end.

Thanks
Peter

Comment: This isn't really an answer