# Why does the VB6 IDE refuse to load valid add-ins?

Tags: vb6

I've recently installed VB6+SP6 on a new Windows 10 PC and it seems to work fine in itself.

But as I'm trying to get IDE add-ins working I'm running into this type of error:

[image: ...could not be loaded. Remove it from the list of available Add-Ins?]

This particular example is from the Microsoft add-in at this link: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/837910/mouse-wheel-events-do-not-work-in-the-visual-basic-6-0-ide

*but others are all doing the same thing.*

I've never seen this before - what is the cause?

Thanks

---

**EDIT:** MZTools 8 and VBAdvance have WORKED even though others have not; those both had their own installer which apparently does something right.

Comment: try re-installing the dll. I have VB6 on my Win 10 pc and I actually went into the Add-In Manager and it shows under Available Add-Ins MouseWheel Fix and Load Behavior is Startup/Loaded. I really don't think we did anything special when we installed the IDE.

Comment: To supplement what Koosh said, try re-registering the DLL

Comment: @koosh thanks, I have tried that but it didn't have an effect. regsvr32 claimed success and was run with admin rights.

Comment: @MarkJ as just noted above...

Comment: Try running the IDE elevated.

Comment: If you do a clean install of IDE, does it show anything under Available Add Ins?